# Nginx doesn't find Symfony2 routes

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, routes, download

I try to run a simple Symfony2 application on a virtual machine. I have Nginx on this VM (generated with PuPHPet and Vagrant), but there's a problem.

**When I try to access to the demo route /demo (local.dev/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/demo), Nginx force me to download a file. It seems it works the same way when I specify a random route.**

I don't know how to solve this problem, I searched while 2 days for a specific configuration of Nginx but I found nothing. Here is my config file for this Symfony app :

```
server {
    server_name test.dev;
    root /var/www/local.dev/Symfony/web;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/sf-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/sf-access.log;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked that php-fpm is running on port 9000?

Comment: Shouldn't your location allow more after the (etc|etc).php? More than (/|$)?

Comment: I tried to change the regex with `^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/.*|$)` but it doesn't change anything. And what do you mean by "Have you checked that php-fpm is running on port 9000" ?

Comment: A PHP interpeter needs to listen on port 9000 in order for nginx to be able to forward. I am not versatile enough with nginx regex's to be sure your new regex is correct.

Comment: Try this:  

```location / { try_files $uri $uri/ /app.php?$args; }```

and for your PHP location, try this pattern:

```location ~ \.php```

Comment: It does not work :( I'm not totally sure my config file is taken in account. How could I verify it?

Comment: I tried to add `location ~ \.php(/.*) { try_files $uri $uri/ /app_dev.php app_dev.php$is_args$args; }` and now i have not a forced download but he doesn't find any route, even root /